# Can´t scroll down

Tags: html, mobile, scroll

I'm trying to scroll down with the following website, in a mobile view and I can't, any suggestions?

The thing is that I understand that this may be happening due to the menu I'm using but I'm not able to make it scroll as a normal

in HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
     
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.1/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,200,300,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- build:js modernizr.touch.js -->
    <script src="elastic/modernizr.touch.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <link href="elastic/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- build:css mfb.css -->
    <link href="elastic/mfb.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- endbuild -->
    
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="elastic/style.css">

    <style>
    .ion-location{
 
  color : #FB0000;
}
  .ion-social-facebook{
 
  color : #3b5998;
}
  .ion-social-googleplus{
 
  color :  #d34836;
}
  .ion-social-instagram-outline{
 
  color : #3f729b;
}

    </style>
    
    
  </head>

  <body>



<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<link href="elastic/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="elastic/ionic.bundle.js"></script>



<ion-header-bar class="bar-positive bar bar-header disable-user-behavior" >

    <h1 class="title">Sobre mí</h1>
</ion-header-bar>

<ion-content delegate-handle="example-scroller" elastic-header="example-elastic-header" overflow-scroll="false" class="scroll-content ionic-scroll  has-header"><div class="scroll" style="transform: translate3d(0px, -1px, 0px) scale(1);" >
    <div id="example-elastic-header" class="background-image" style="transform-origin: center bottom 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0.5px, 0px) scale(1, 1); background-image: url(&quot;los7aguacates.jpg&quot;);"></div>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="padding">
            <h1>Los 7 aguacates </h1>
            <p>Mi vida ha estado siempre marcada por mis grandes amores y pasiones:<br><br>
                -   La nutrición, y la posibilidad de “curar lo incurable” a través de una alimentación adecuada.<br><br>
                -   La gente, y la posibilidad de mejorar su vida, aumentar la autoestima, transformar la mente y acompañar a las personas durante el proceso de cambio mientras observo los maravillosos pasos hacia la salud y el bienestar.<br><br>

                -   Mi país, Polonia y España, que por elección es mi segunda casa.<br><br>
                -   Los aguacates, que no sé muy bien por qué, pero se han hecho una parte inseparable de mí ;)
                "</p>
            <p>Justo por eso estoy donde estoy, hago lo que hago y …!quiero seguir! </p><p>

            Todos tenemos el poder de impactar en la vida de otra persona. ¿Por qué no aprovecharlo para mejorar la salud y la calidad de vida de los demás? Quiero que la buena alimentación se haga viral (¡ya ves que necesito tu ayuda para ello!) e impacte en todas las personas, mostrando también a los peques (¡que son las nuevas generaciones!) qué significa comer bien y cómo. A través de una vida saludable, se pueden evitar muchos problemas de salud. 

            </p><p>Únete a mi movimiento, al movimiento de los7aguacates, un movimiento que promueve la alimentación sana como forma de vida, como base para una existencia más plena y feliz. ¡Un movimiento que quiere “curar lo incurable”! Comiendo bien, compartiendo recetas, dando ejemplo tú también impactas positivamente en los demás, ¿quieres ser mi ayudante? Te necesito, necesito tu impacto para llegar a otras personas. ¡Formemos un equipo! Comer bien es fácil y divertido. ¡Yo te lo mostraré!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="list">

        </div>
    </div>
    </div><div class="scroll-bar scroll-bar-v"><div class="scroll-bar-indicator scroll-bar-fade-out" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 1px, 0px) scaleY(1); height: 356px;"></div></div></ion-content>
<ul id="menu" class="mfb-component--tr mfb-fountain " data-mfb-toggle="hover">
    <li class="mfb-component__wrap">
        <a href="#" class="mfb-component__button--main">
            <i class="mfb-component__main-icon--resting ion-navicon-round"></i>
            <i class="mfb-component__main-icon--active ion-close-round"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="mfb-component__list">
            <li>
                <a href="external://https://www.facebook.com/los7aguacates/" data-mfb-label="Sígueme en Facebook" class="mfb-component__button--child">
                    <i class="mfb-component__child-icon ion-social-facebook"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="external://https://www.instagram.com/los7aguacates/" data-mfb-label="Sígueme en Instagram" class="mfb-component__button--child">
                    <i class="mfb-component__child-icon ion-social-instagram-outline"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="external://https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mubiquo." data-mfb-label="Valora la app" class="mfb-component__button--child">
                    <i class="mfb-component__child-icon ion-heart"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<section id="panel" class="panel">




</section>
<!-- build:js mfb.js -->
<script src="elastic/mfb.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
<script>

    var panel = document.getElementById('panel'),
        menu = document.getElementById('menu'),
        showcode = document.getElementById('showcode'),
        selectFx = document.getElementById('selections-fx'),
        selectPos = document.getElementById('selections-pos'),
        // demo defaults
        effect = 'mfb-zoomin',
        pos = 'mfb-component--br';

    showcode.addEventListener('click', _toggleCode);
    selectFx.addEventListener('change', switchEffect);
    selectPos.addEventListener('change', switchPos);

    function _toggleCode() {
        panel.classList.toggle('viewCode');
    }

    function switchEffect(e){
        effect = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
        renderMenu();
    }

    function switchPos(e){
        pos = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
        renderMenu();
    }

    function renderMenu() {
        menu.style.display = 'none';
        // ?:-)
        setTimeout(function() {
            menu.style.display = 'block';
            menu.className = pos + effect;
        },1);
    }

</script>



<script src="elastic/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you try? [ion-scroll](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/directive/ionScroll/)

Comment: Not sure if it's related to your issue or not but: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" (Line 143 column 10)